# $\mathbb{R}$ without the origin is a covering space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}$ be equivalent iff there exists an integer $n$ such that $(x_2,y_2)=(2^nx_1,2^{-n}y_1)$. Let $f$ be the quotient map.

> How to show: $f$ is a covering map and quotient space is not Hausdorff?

THoughts:
I know that $(0,\infty)=\bigsqcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}[2^n,2^{n+1})$ and $(-\infty,0)=\bigsqcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(-2^{n+1},-2^n]$.

Is the quotient space then $((-2,1]\cup[1,2))^2$?
What are the sheets?
And how does non-Hausdorfness follow?

Comment: Are you sure you copied this problem correctly? Using the formula $(x_2,y_2)=(2^nx_1,2^ny_1)$, the quotient space is homeomorphic to a torus $S^1 \times S^1$ which is Hausdorff. The quotient map which shows this is $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to S^1 \times S^1$ defined by $$f(x,y) = \biggl(\bigl(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)\bigr),\bigl(\cos(2 \pi \log_2(r)),\sin(2 \pi \log_2(r)\bigr)\biggr)
$$where $(r,\theta)$ are polar coordinates for $(x,y)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher You are right it should be $2^{-n}y_1$, sorry

Comment: I edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if the quotient space were $((-2,1] \cup [1,2))^2$ then it would be Hausdorff, so that cannot be right.

A wiser strategy might be not to attempt a global description of the space, but instead to attempt a direct proof of the two properties required.

---

For showing $f$ is a covering map, I'll give a big hint.

First notice that the map $f$ may be described in terms of the orbits of a group acting by homeomorphisms, namely the group $\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ by the formula
$$n \cdot (x,y) = (2^n x, 2^{-n} y)
$$
Now let me abstract. Consider any group $G$ acting on a topological space $X$ by homeomorphisms. There is an equivalence relation where $p,q \in X$ are equivalent if there exists $g \in G$ such that $g \cdot p = q$. The *orbit* of $p \in X$ is its equivalence class $\{g\cdot p | g \in G\}$. Let $X/G$ denote the natural quotient space, and $X \mapsto X/G$ the natural quotient map, which maps $x$ to its orbit.

> Theorem: The quotient map $X \mapsto X/G$ is a covering map if and only if for each $x \in X$ there exists an open set $U \subset X$ containing $U$ such that for all $g \in G$ we have $(g \cdot U) \cap U = \emptyset$.

To complete the hint, given $x \in \mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ find the open set $U$.

---

For showing that the quotient space is not Hausdorff, you must find two points $p,q \in \mathbb{R}^2$ which are not elements of the same orbit, such that for every $\epsilon>0$, the orbits of the balls $U=B_\epsilon(p)$ and $V=B_\epsilon(q)$ are not disjoint. That is, the sets
$$\mathbb{Z} \cdot U = \{(2^m w, 2^{-m} x) \,\big|\, m \in \mathbb{Z}, (w,x) \in B_r(p)\}
$$
and
$$\mathbb{Z} \cdot V = \{(2^n y ,2^{-n} z) \,\big|\, n \in \mathbb{Z}, (y,z) \in B_r(q)\}
$$
are not disjoint. The points $p=(1,0)$ and $q=(0,1)$ have this property: for any $r>0$, if $n > \log_{2}(r)$ then $(1,2^{-n}) \in U$ and $ (2^{-n},1) \in V$ and the points $(1,2^{-n})$ and $(2^{-n},1)$ are in the same orbit.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without orbits?

Comment: Other than just changing the language, i.e. replacing the word "orbits" by the word "equivalence classes", I don't think so. You really do have to think about the equivalence classes. Since these equivalence classes are defined by the group action, I find it convenient to refer to them as "orbits", to remind myself that the definition of the equivalence classes is closely tied to the group action.